# Change color of buffer name in mode-line

Tags: emacs, elisp

It would be nice to have the buffer/file name more visible inside the mode-line specially when working with many files.

How to change the color of buffer name inside mode-line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just customize face `mode-line-buffer-id`: `M-x customize-face`.

I use this value, for instance (from my `custom-file`):

```
 (mode-line-buffer-id ((t (:overline "red" :underline "red"))))
```

IOW, I have both an overline and an underline, for the buffer name.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use:

`(set-face-attribute 'mode-line-buffer-id nil :foreground "black")`

or for carbon emacs:

`(set-face-attribute 'modeline-buffer-id nil :foreground "black")`